# NotFoundHttpException in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

> my html link code

```
<a href="{{route('blog') }}">Details</a>
```

> my route code

```
Route::get('blog', array('as' => 'blog', 'uses' => function(){
  return view('blog');
}));
```

> error log

```
in RouteCollection.php line 161
    at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 750
    at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 659
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 635
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in
```

please help me to find this error.Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure this is the full error that you receive?

Comment: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Comment: Try `Route::get('blog', array('as' => 'blog', function(){
  return view('blog');
}));`

Comment: How your link looks like in generated HTML? `<a href="???">Details</a>`.

Comment: http://localhost:8000/%7B%7B%20URL::route('blog')%20%7D%7D

Comment: This url was generated after clicking "Details"

Comment: This url is not generated at all :(

Comment: what is the problem ???

Comment: What is the filename of your blog view file? view.php or view.blade.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your view file is not being parsed as blade template file. The braces only work in blade files so try using just PHP...

```
<a href="<?php echo route('blog'); ?>">Details</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

`<a href="{{url('blog') }}">Details</a>`

instead of the current: `<a href="{{route('blog') }}">Details</a>`

Comment: So as far as this goes, what is the format that this will be in? blog/{article}/{id} ? try removing this: `array('as' => 'blog', 'uses' =>`  as well as one of the final `)`'s

Comment: there is no blog/{article}/{id} .I just need to access page using route file.Still no parameters was passed.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the route cache by running the
`php artisan route:clear` command and see if the route actually exists with `php artisan route:list`

Also, the "uses" keyword is not necessary in this example

```
Route::get('blog', array('as' => 'blog', function(){
    return view('blog');
}));
```

If that doesn't help, then we're going to need the full routes file, because everything seems to be ok here.